# Failed to build React on github actions

Tags: reactjs, github-actions

This is the first time i'm using github action, and when I build I get this error.
The error happend during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve "./pages/Product" from "src/App.jsx"
[image]

```js
name: Publish Website to Web Hosting
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name: FTP-Deploy-Action
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@master
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: Build Project
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build
        env:
          CI: false

      - name: List output files
        run: find build/ -print

      - name: FTP-Deploy-Action
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.3
        with:
          server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
          username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
          local-dir: build/
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots of errors, post the actual text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check, maybe you need `cd` command before build or maybe different `remote-dir` in ftp server, i got `/www/site.name`

I also have string (maybe its overkill but worked for me):
`CI='' npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

In src/App.jsx file ./pages/Product component is not accessible. Make sure the path to the component are correct.

Try using [absolute imports](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports)